# How to open Anaconda Prompt from Windows Explorer URL?

Tags: terminal, virtualenv, miniconda, anaconda3

I would like to open the Anaconda Prompt within a current folder using the URL in Windows Explorer similar to how you open a Git Bash terminal using "git-bash here".

I was unable to find a way to do this.

I tried to add the installation directory to the system PATH variable but that didn't work.

Any ideas if this is possible?